# How this does equation simplify to

Tags: c++, directx

In Frank D Lunas DirectX11 book, on page 356, section 9.5.4, he has an equation

```
(rs, gs, bs) * (as, as, as) + (rd, gd, bd) * (1-as, 1-as, 1-as)
    = as(rd, gd, bd) + (1-as)(rs, gs, bs)
```

Where * is component wise multiplication.

(r, g, b) refers to colours.

Comment: I'd say this isn't related to mathematics or something, but from color theory. Just a wild guess.

Comment: did you swap `as` and `1-as`?

Comment: No, (rd, gd, bd) and (rs, gs, bs) are swapped, but I don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(rs, gs, bs) * (as, as, as) + (rd, gd, bd) * (1-as, 1-as, 1-as)`

Expand the component wise multiplication

`(as*rs, as*gs, as*bs) + ((1-as)*rd, (1-as)*gd, (1-as)*bd)`

Factorize

`as(rs, gs, bs) + (1-as)(rd, gd, bd)`

I think this must be an error in the book.

Comment: There are some errors I've found in the book, so it could be.

Comment: Is there a website for the book? There may be an erratum.

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't look correct. It should be:

```
as*(rs, gs, bs) + (1-as)(rd, gd, bd)
```

I'm assuming this is a transparency operation using source alpha.

Answer (score 0):

As you have written it, I think the equation is wrong. Since `*` represents component wise multiplication:

```
(rs, gs, bs) * (as, as, as) = as(rs, gs, bs)
(rd, gd, bd) * (1-as, 1-as, 1-as) = (1-as)(rd, gd, bd)
```

So:

```
(rs, gs, bs) * (as, as, as) + (rd, gd, bd) * (1-as, 1-as, 1-as)
    = as(rs, gs, bs) + (1-as)(rd, gd, bd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a mistake in the book.

```
(rs, gs, bs) * (as, as, as) + (rd, gd, bd) * (1-as, 1-as, 1-as)
    = (rs*as, gs*as, bs*as) + (rd*(1-as), gd*(1-as), bd*(1-as))
    = as(rd, gd, bd) + (1-as)(rs, gs, bs)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe because the component wise multiplication (a,b,c)*(d,d,d) is the same like a simple scalar multiplication on a row vector (a, b, c) * d?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%2Cb%2Cc%29%28d%2Cd%2Cd%29
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%2Cb%2Cc%29+d

just guessing